# Triangulation of polygons with all triangles having a common angle

Tags: discrete-geometry, computational-geometry, triangles

Following [Partition of polygons into 'strongly acute' and 'strongly obtuse' triangles](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/433413/partition-of-polygons-into-strongly-acute-and-strongly-obtuse-triangles), we record another triangulation question.

**Question:** Given an n-vertex polygonal region ("n-gon") and a real number $\theta$ <  $\pi$, is it always possible to partition the n-gon into finitely many triangles such that each triangle has one angle equal to $\theta$? If the answer is "not always" (which appears to be the case), *deciding* whether such a triangulation exists for a given polygon and $\theta$ becomes another question. And in the cases where such a triangulation is possible, we could try to minimize the number of triangles.

An earlier post from the same ballpark: [Cutting convex polygons into triangles of same diameter](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/392596/cutting-convex-polygons-into-triangles-of-same-diameter)